# makefile parse target to define dependencies

Tags: makefile

I have source files in several directories and I want to compile them in a one unique temporary directory, currently I use this target to create my object files :

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o : 
    @echo "Compiling $@"
    $(VERBOSE) $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ $(shell echo "$(SOURCES)" | sed 's/ /\n/g' | sed -nr '/\/$(*F)\.c/p')
```

It is working well but when I modify a source file, the object one is not recompiled. So I have to add the source file to the dependencies.

But this target doesn't work :

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o : $(shell echo "$(SOURCES)" | sed 's/ /\n/g' | sed -nr '/\/$(*F)\.c/p')
    @echo "Compiling $@"
    $(VERBOSE) $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDES) -o $@ $^
```

Is there any way to use target name in dependencies ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/)...

Use a pattern rule like:

```
obj/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

to tell `make` that an object file `obj/<name>.o` is to be compiled from a source file
`<name>.c`

In conjunction with this, use the [`VPATH` special variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html)
to inform `make` of directories in which it should look for any `<name>.c`, if it is not
in the current directory.

Also, add an [order-only prerequisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html)
to the pattern rule to ensure that the directory (`obj`) to which your object files are compiled
exists when needed:

```
obj/%.o: %.c | obj
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

So for example, with project structure:

```
./
-- Makefile
-- aa/
    -- main.c
-- bb/
    -- foo.c
-- obj/ #<-- Compile object files in here
-- prog #<- program to be built
```

And:

**Makefile**

```
VPATH := aa:bb
SRCS := foo.c main.c
OBJS := $(addprefix obj/, $(SRCS:.c=.o))

.PHONY: all clean

all: prog

prog: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)

obj/%.o: %.c | obj
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

obj:
    mkdir $@

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJS) prog
```

the build runs like:

```
$ make
cc   -c -o obj/foo.o bb/foo.c
cc   -c -o obj/main.o aa/main.c
cc  -o prog obj/foo.o obj/main.o
```